# How do I run an eclipse project without eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I want to send my project I made in eclipse to others, so I tried running the project in my workspace. But I don't have a software to run it.(besides eclipse) What software should I use?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have a software to run it.(besides eclipse) What software should I use?

You should use Java. Eclipse is just an IDE, so it doesn't run your Java programs. Java does. Export your program as a JAR, and if you have Java installed, you can run the JAR by double-clicking on it, or by running it from the command line:

```
java -jar file.jar
```

Comment: I tried running it with java, but java opened and had an error that said it was unable to launch the application. Is is supposed to be called java web start launcher?

Comment: No it shouldn't. Are you using AWT?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to export it before. Now I actually have the executable jar file, but nothing happens when I double click it. Do I need to convert it into a manifest file?

Comment: If you try to run it with the command line as I described, what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

[First Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sZMw.png)

[Second Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzAYK.png)

[Third step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Nklw.png)

voilà!

Comment: The images for "Second Step" and "Third step" look identical. Was this intended?